# Can't gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

This question has been asked many times before but it seems everyone else is trying it on OS X. I'm on Ubuntu.

Here's what I get when I try to `sudo gem install rails`:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.3...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.3...
file 'lib' not found
```

What do I have to do to get it to work?

I know it's not working because of this:

```
$ rails
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  To run 'rails' please ask your administrator to install the package 'rails'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential
```

Comment: What does ruby have to do with not finding the rails executable installed?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

> $ gem environment

and

> $ echo $PATH

Ensure that your EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY shows up in your $PATH variable. If it doesn't, add it in your shell startup files. [(eg. your `.profile`)](https://serverfault.com/questions/44275/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It does. (Stack Overflow's comment length minimum is stupid.)

Comment: This definitely works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It's working, as indicated by the `1 gem installed` line.

The error messages you're getting is because the Rails documentation won't generate--many gems have similar problems with their auto-documenting feature. This won't impair the functionality of the gem, and chances are you'll go to [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for documentation anyway.

If the Rails installation actually failed, you'd see something along the lines of (might vary--the example below is from a native extension which may differ):

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:

[stacktrace]

Gem files will remain installed in /path/to/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /path/to/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

If you check `gem list`, Rails will be in the list.

Comment: See my edit--you should be seeing a completely different error message if the installation failed. Check `gem list` and confirm that Rails is present there--the problem seems to be with your $PATH or other related issue if you can't use the `rails` command line command.

Comment: Rails doesn't show up under `gem list`. The only thing there is `rake`.

Comment: And that's the only error message you're getting? It doesn't make sense. Do you by any chance have multiple versions of Ruby and/or rvm installed?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by installing rdoc, like this. However you are on Ubuntu and I'm on Mac.

```
Simon-Strandgaards-Mac-mini:Desktop neoneye$ gem install rails
Fetching: i18n-0.6.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-3.2.1.gem (100%)
...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-ssl-1.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for railties-3.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.22...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.1...
file 'lib' not found
Simon-Strandgaards-Mac-mini:Desktop neoneye$ gem install rdoc
Fetching: rdoc-3.12.gem (100%)
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
Successfully installed rdoc-3.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rdoc-3.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for rdoc-3.12...
Simon-Strandgaards-Mac-mini:Desktop neoneye$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.1...
Simon-Strandgaards-Mac-mini:Desktop neoneye$
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by installing it with the rails decl:

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
Installing the latest RubyGems manually & then installing rails worked for me.